# Kafka got shutdown for 2 days so i am missing logs, is there any way to retrieve those? and how can i prevent kafka to ever shutdown?

Tags: apache-kafka

Kafka got shutdown for 2 days so i am missing logs, is there any way to retrieve those? and how can i prevent Kafka to ever shutdown?

I have zookeeper service and Kafka service? and Kafka keeps shutting down, what can be a solution to this problem?

this is my service

> ---

```
[Unit]
Requires=zookeeper.service
After=zookeeper.service

[Service]
Type=simple
User=wapteam
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '/etc/default/kafka_2.13-2.8.0/bin/kafka-server-start.sh  /etc/default/kafka_2.13-2.8.0/config/server.properties'
ExecStop=/etc/default/kafka_2.13-2.8.0/bin/kafka-server-stop.sh
Restart=on-abnormal

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

---

i have created service which restart on failure but it gets stuck on shutdown command of that service. please help.

Comment: The reason kafka broker shutted down is important. Investigate kafka server logs.

Comment: ok but is there anyway to retrieve those logs?

Comment: Well, you can configure log4j to write to `/var/log/kafka`, but it's not there by default, and we can't tell where you've currently put the logs other than `journalctl -u kafka`